# norm vs lognorm plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I want to plot a Normal versus a Log-Normal function using following code:

```
from scipy.stats import norm, lognorm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# example: r(t) = ln(1 + R(t)) ~ N(0.05, (0.5)^2))
#          1 + R(t) = exp(r(t)) ~ logNormal(0.05, (0.5)^2)
#          R(t) = e(r(t)) - 1 ~ logNormal(0.05, (0.5)^2) - 1
#  
# plot normal and log normal density
mu = .05
sd = .5
x = np.linspace(mu - 3 * sd, mu + 3 * sd, 100)
plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x, mu, sd), label="Normal") 
plt.plot(exp(x)-1, lognorm.pdf(exp(x), mu, sd), '--', label="Log-Normal")
```

What is wrong ? I expect something like: [image: norm vs lognorm]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of parameters in the lognorm.pdf function is not what you think!
When you reverse the order to:
`lognorm.pdf(exp(x), sd, mu)`, you get the plot you were expecting. 

EDIT: The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html#scipy.stats.lognorm) gives `pdf(x, s, loc=0, scale=1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! How nasty! order of parameters for norm and lognorm is reverse ?! Why is it not consistent ?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html#scipy.stats.lognorm gives pdf(x, s, loc=0, scale=1)

Comment: By the way - I think that the reason for the different order is the fact that a lognorm distribution would usually be expected to have a "loc" of zero; thus it's a parameter you would not normally set, and it's made available as an optional parameter with a default of 0.

Comment: Same can be said for scale=1. This looks like a bug, either in the code or the documentation is wrong. And one should expect consistency between norm and lognorm.

Comment: @rdw The code matches the documentation.  It might be a poor design choice, but not a bug.  And it almost certainly can never be changed, because any code that uses the current signatures would be broken by flipping the arguments to match what you expect.

Comment: @rdw - I think the documentation must be correct (in the sense that it reflects the way the function is implemented), since reversing the arguments gave us the plot you were expecting. I do agree that it is extremely annoying and inconsistent.

Comment: @tcaswell how do you mean the code matches the documentaton ? Documentation says loc first, scale second, same as for norm ?

Comment: @rdw you aren't setting `scale` you are setting `s` (which is what is pasted into the answer)

Comment: @tcaswell ok, s is shape is sigma, while scale is exp(mu), in the docs. Not sure I understand this but ok. Anyway confusing. In R it is simply dnorm(x, mean, sd) and dlnorm(x, mean, sd).

Comment: @rdw I suspect the logic is that the parameters which are non-linear to compute are required, and the parameters which can be done linearly are optional.

Answer (score 2):

A brief aside on reading python documentation/how function calls work:

Arguments with out default values i.e. `some_fun(a,b)` are positional arguments which are required (or python will raise an error about number of arguments) and assigned based on the position in the function call.  If have a default value i.e., `some_other_fun(a,b,c=None,d=0)` they are called keyword arguments and are optional.   You can use the optional arguments in two ways, if you do not use the keyword, then they are treated like positional arguments.  If you give less arguments than the total number of arguments in the signature, then those values are assigned in order and the remaining arguments take their default values.  You can also use the keyword form to assign just the optional arguments you want with out providing a value for everything in the list before them i.e. `some_other_fun(1,2,d=3)` is different than `some_other_fun(1,2,3)`

So, when you call `lognorm.pdf(x,sd,mu)` you are binding as `x=x`, `s=sd` , `loc=mu`, `scale=1` where as with `norm.pdf(x,mu,sd)` you are binding `x=x`, `loc=mu`, `scale=sd`

Also see this section of the  [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions).

Comment: I know how python function calls work, that's not the point. scipy.stats is inconsistant in its function signatures for norm and lognorm. Look at R which has that consistency.